# Endless List View in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-listfragment

I want to implement a `List View` in `Fragment`. Size of the list can be more than 1000 which includes images in left and name and type will be right. I am able to implement `CustomArrayAdapter` and List View but i don't know how to load only specific number of items or only those which are visible. I want that if user `scroll down` then only hit the server and load the images and data.

How can i implement this kind of `List View` in `Fragment`?

I don't know much about `andorid`. Please help me out to solve this problem.

**Thank in advance**

Comment: I don't know why my question get down voted.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967994/how-to-populate-a-listview-asynchronously, this _Making ListView Scrolling Smooth_: http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html and this _Loading Views On Demand_ :http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/loading-ondemand.html

Comment: you have to use pull to refresh for this

Comment: i found simmilar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080811/android-endless-list)

Comment: @MeenalSharma i want to load data when user scroll down the list not refresh the list i mean not pull down

Comment: please see my editted answer

Comment: @MeenalSharma i want to implement endless list view. Not pull to refresh.

Comment: what you want is called lazy loading. for images i know a few libraries like 'URLImageViewHelper', 'UniversalImageLoader'... looking for such things for other type of data.

Comment: @kaustuv but those libraries only for images lazy loading not for the data.

Comment: @Kaustuv i need endless List view means display only 10-20 item then when user will scroll down then show loding and then load rest of 10-20 items. Like google-play, facebook etc

Comment: hey i think this might work. suppose you have an array list of  10 items to show. When user scrolls use listView.getLastVisiblePosition()==dataSource.size() to get to know when user reaches end of list. Then do your network call to get new set of data, add this to the old data source of your list view and call notifyDataSetChanged(). This way new items will get added at end of list

Answer (score 0):

The listview class has a couple of useful methods to deal with that:

```
 int lastItem = listView.getLastVisiblePosition();  

 int firstItem = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
```

What you could do is load an appropriate batch of data from the server (say 100 items), then override the method onScoll() of the listview to keep track on what are those values over time, when the user arrives to the end of the batch (say, the position 100), you can load the next batch and notify the adapter that the list has changed.