# Add Data into Listview Runtime using Custom Adapter

Tags: java, android, listview, baseadapter

[image]

**PROBLEM :** when i am click on add button then all data are clear and only one item is shows.... i want to Show Old items as well as new added item...

this is my code.....

MODEL class

```
public class GroupModel {
    ArrayList<String> G_member=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> G_name = new ArrayList<String>();


    public ArrayList<String> getG_member() {
        return G_member;
    }

    public void setG_member(ArrayList<String> g_member) {
        G_member = g_member;
    }
    public void addToGmember(String gname){
        this.G_member.add(gname);
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getG_name() {
        return G_name;
    }

    public void setG_name(ArrayList<String> g_name) {
        G_name = g_name;
    }
    public void addToGname(String name){
        this.G_name.add(name);
    }
}
```

MAIN ACTIVITY

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Context context=this;
    private ListView lv;
    ImageView plus_img;// plus button to add GROUP Runtime.
    GroupModel model = new GroupModel();
    GroupAdapter adapter;
    ListView myListView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.group__listview);
        myListView = lv;
        //plus image
        plus_img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.add_img);
        plus_img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                model.addToGname("jignesh");
                model.addToGmember("8");
                ArrayList<GroupModel> l = new ArrayList<GroupModel>();
                l.add(model);
           //     adapter.setListData(getListData());
                myListView.setAdapter(new GroupAdapter(context, l));
            //    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });


        adapter= new GroupAdapter(context,getListData());
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

}

    private ArrayList getListData() {
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        int untilloop;

        if(model.getG_member().size()>10)
        {
            untilloop = model.getG_member().size();
            for (int i=0;i<untilloop;i++)
            {
                model.getG_member();
                model.getG_name();
                list.add(model);
            }
        }
        else{
            untilloop=10;
            for(int i = 0; i <untilloop; i++){
                model.getG_name().add("raj "+i );
                model.getG_member().add(""+i);
                list.add(model);
            }
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

ADAPTER class

```
public class GroupAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    ArrayList<GroupModel> glist;
    Context context;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public GroupAdapter(Context mainActivity, ArrayList<GroupModel> glist) {
        context = mainActivity;
        this.glist=glist;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }
    public void setListData(ArrayList<GroupModel> data){
        glist = data;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return glist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return glist.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView==null){
         //  LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_list_data,null);
            holder= new ViewHolder();
            holder.g_number=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_g_number);
            holder.g_name=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_g_name);
            holder.nxt_aerrow=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_nxt);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.g_number.setText(glist.get(position).getG_member().get(position).toString());
        holder.g_name.setText(glist.get(position).getG_name().get(position).toString());

        holder.nxt_aerrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context,"image click",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }
    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView g_number,g_name;
        ImageView nxt_aerrow;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ListView with a custom adapter, adding elements one by one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9416215/listview-with-a-custom-adapter-adding-elements-one-by-one)

Comment: In OnClick you are creating array object and passing it to your adapter will create only row every time. Create that array list at global level and add your Group member in it. will hopefully solve your problem

Comment: thank you  for reply,,,,I want to add one row when OnClick ...

Comment: i am not getting you @Drup Desai..

Comment: Okay then declare you Arraylist as global variable and add your group member in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this add the method in Adapter:

```
public void addItem(GroupModel groupModel){
   yourList.add(groupModel);
  notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And On Click method do this,

```
plus_img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                model.addToGname("jignesh");
                model.addToGmember("8");

                adapter.addItem(model);
            }
        });
```

Comment: yup.. its working...now i want to delete any particular item if long pressed... so how can i achieve ?

Comment: @RjzSatvara One question per post, please. Your posted question has been answered. If you have another, post a new question. Better yet, search first. That question has definitely been answered here before.

Answer (score 0):

You always got one element in your `ListView` because every time you click on `add button`, you create new `ArrayList` then you add one element to your `ArrayList` => your `ArrayList` always have one item => your `ListView` always have one item

So Simply move `ArrayList<GroupModel> l = new ArrayList<GroupModel>();` to outside of `plus_img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()`

```
...
ArrayList<GroupModel> l = new ArrayList<GroupModel>();
...
plus_img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               ...
            }
});
```

Comment: inside `setOnClickListener`, can you write a logcat for print the `ArrayList size`. and then tell me the array size increase correctly when you press on add button or not

Answer (score 0):

Try below code in you activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

Context context=this;
private ListView lv;
ImageView plus_img;// plus button to add GROUP Runtime.
GroupModel model = new GroupModel();
GroupAdapter adapter;
ListView myListView;
ArrayList<GroupModel> l = new ArrayList<GroupModel>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.group__listview);
    myListView = lv;
    //plus image
    plus_img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.add_img);
    plus_img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            model.addToGname("jignesh");
            model.addToGmember("8");
            l.add(model);
       //     adapter.setListData(getListData());
            myListView.setAdapter(new GroupAdapter(context, l));
        //    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });


    adapter= new GroupAdapter(context,getListData());
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

}

private ArrayList getListData() {
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    int untilloop;

    if(model.getG_member().size()>10)
    {
        untilloop = model.getG_member().size();
        for (int i=0;i<untilloop;i++)
        {
            model.getG_member();
            model.getG_name();
            list.add(model);
        }
    }
    else{
        untilloop=10;
        for(int i = 0; i <untilloop; i++){
            model.getG_name().add("raj "+i );
            model.getG_member().add(""+i);
            list.add(model);
        }
    }

    return list;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

adapter= new GroupAdapter(context,getListData());
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

if u observe this line you are setting whatever getListData() is returning...so declare a new Global List and later do the following

```
globalList.addAll(getListData());
adapter= new GroupAdapter(context,globalList);
```

Now you can preserve both old as well as new data...you maintain a new list where in you have all the data....and manipulate using that "globalList"

Thank you